# how to reduce typing for properties assignment (destructuring,...)?

Tags: javascript

How to reduce typing for:

```
class C {
    Constructor(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
       this.a=a;
       this.b=b; 
       this.c=c; 
       this.d=d; 
       this.e=e; 
    }
}
```

for doing something like this:

```
class C {
    Constructor(param: [a,b,c,d,e,f]) {
       this=param;
    }
}
```

but this syntax doesn't work

Comment: Use TypeScript, then you get parameter properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass in an object instead, then use `Object.assign`:

```js
class C {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}

const c = new C({ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e' });
console.log(c);
```

Note that `constructor` must be lower-cased.

You could also use argument rest syntax, allowing you to avoid repitition when calling `new C`:

```js
class C {
  constructor(...args) {
    const props = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(
      args
        .slice(0, 5)
        .map((val, i) => [props[i], val])
    );
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}

const c = new C('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
console.log(c);
```

As Bergi notes, you could also call `Array.prototype.entries` on `props` for less code:

```js
class C {
  constructor(...args) {
    const props = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    for (const [i, prop] of props.entries()) {
      this[prop] = args[i];
    }
  }
}

const c = new C('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
console.log(c);
```

Comment: TBH, `Object.fromEntries` is a bit too much here. KISS: `for (const [i, prop] of props.entries()) this[prop] = args[i];`

Comment: Notice that the `Object.assign` solution requires the argument to have exactly the desired properties, no more no less.